# My website has a line where the sidebar used to be, How do I remove it?

Tags: php, html, sidebar

How do I remove the line on the right had side going down, it used to be a sidebar.  Any help is appreciated, thank you.

My site is here: http://mcj.site40.net/

An image pinpointing the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eiiec.png

Comment: I see no line on Chrome...

Comment: I see no line on Firefox...

Comment: I see no line in Safari... Monitor burn-in?

Comment: It is there... it is a light brown vertical line on white.

Comment: I just added a pic, its weird if people cant see it?!? http://i.stack.imgur.com/Eiiec.png

Comment: He means the line right beside the main content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line is part of the background image on your `#wrap`

You will need to alter the image.

This is the image:
http://mcj.site40.net/style/images/wrap.gif

Comment: To add: That image is used for the background of the main content and is repeated vertically in CSS to create a line. Just go into the image and paint it all the same color, and it should be fine.

Comment: @MrXenotype I wouldn't go an paint it all the same color as the sides of the image are also the borders.  Just try to target that one or two pixels that create the line.  Alternatively you could ditch the image all together and create the border purely with css.

Comment: true, true. http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/1594/wrap.gif here is the altered image. Just overwrite that image in your server.

Comment: +1 for your effort on editing Jrod's image file.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you have a background image here. Remove that to get rid of the line.

```
#wrap {
background: url("http://mcj.site40.net/style/images/wrap.gif") repeat-y scroll center top #FFFFFF;
margin: 40px auto 30px;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
width: 952px;
```

}

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as to remove it, because the image also includes the side borders... Just use my altered image: http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/1594/wrap.gif

Comment: Yes, I agree with you MrXenotype.